# If $a_n = a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}$ where $a_0 = 2$ and $a_1 = 1$, what is the recurrence relation for $a_{2^n-1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, infinite-product

Recurrence relation for $A002249_{(2^n-1)}$

I'm interested about the sequence [A002249](https://oeis.org/A002249) in the OEIS and I have a question about this sequence :

$$a_n = a_{n-1} - 2a_{n-2};\, a_0 = 2, a_1 = 1.$$

Is it possible to find a reccurence relation for $a_{2^n-1}$ with that form $a_{2^n-1} = ba_{n-1}^p - ca_{n-2}^q - ... - da_{n-m}^r$ ?

Here is what I observed :

You can write the sequence with that tips (start at $n=2, a_{2^n-1} = -5$):

For example :

- $a_3 = -5$
- $a_7 = (-5)\cdot1-2^3 = -13$
- $a_{15} = ((-5)\cdot1-2^3)\cdot(1^2-2^5)-2^7 = 275$
- $a_{31} = (((-5)\cdot1-2^3)\cdot(1^2-2^5)-2^7)\cdot((1^2-2^5)^2-2^9)-2^{15} = 90707$
- $a_{63} = ((((-5)\cdot1-2^3)\cdot(1^2-2^5)-2^7)\cdot((1^2-2^5)^2-2^9)-2^{15})\cdot(((1^2-2^5)^2-2^9)^2-2^{17})-2^{31} = 4249990355$
  etc.

By generalization you can write :
$a_{2^n-1} = ((((((((-5)\cdot1-2^3)\cdot(1^2-2^5)-2^7)\cdot((1^2-2^5)^2-2^9)-2^{15})\cdot(((1^2-2^5)^2-2^9)^2-2^{17})-2^{31})\cdot((((1^2-2^5)^2-2^9)^2-2^{17})^2-2^{33})-2^{63})-...-2^{2^{n-2}+1})^2-2^{2^{n-1}+1})-2^{2^{n}-1}$

But I have no idea how to have a sequence from this.

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Try to make your question self-contained. So define the sequence in the quesrion. You can still include the link.

Comment: There won't be a simple linear homogeneous recurrence.

Comment: But you might get a recurrence like $b_{n+1}=cb_n^2+d,$ for some constants $c,d.$ (Where $b_{n}=a_{2^n-1}.$)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thanks a lot for your tips ! Yes I thought about that too for the recurrence but I can't find it

Comment: Basically, use the formula $a_n=z^n+\overline z^n,$ where $z=\frac{1+\sqrt{-7}}2.$ Then $z\overline z=2$ and $z+\overline z=1.$ Not sure it will work, but it might.

Comment: You easily get $a_{2^{n+1}-2}=a_{2^n-1}^2-2.$ But I'm not seeing how to get $a_{2^{n+1}-1}$ from there.

Comment: The $O(n)$ time method to compute these value is the method of repeated squaring, applied to computing the trace of $A^{2^n-1},$ where $A$ is the matrix described in the link. That can be done recursively, and you can come up with a recursive formula, but is requires a bunch of variables to be recursed, not just one.

Comment: If one variable isn't possible, I'm ok with more

Comment: Note that the explicit formula for $a_n$ is $$a_n = (\frac{1 + i \sqrt{7}}{2})^n + (\frac{1 - i \sqrt{7}}{2})^n$$

Answer (score 2):

You can get a recurrence using two sequences, where one is the sequence you want. Don't know if you can do better.

Show that $$a_{2k}=a_k^2-2^{k+1}.$$

Then let $b_n=a_{2^n -1}, c_n=a_{2^n}.$

Then when $k=2^n$ in $(1),$ we get $$c_{n+1}=c_n^2-2^{2^{ n}+1}.$$

And when $k=2^n-1$ in $(1),$ we get $$b_n^2-2^{2^n}=a_{2^{n+1}-2}=\frac{b_{n+1}-c_{n+1}}2$$

Re-arranging, we get: $$b_{n+1}=2b_{n}^2-2^{2^n+1}+c_{n+1}=2b_n^2+c_n^2-2^{2^n+2}$$

So you can compute $(b_{n+1},c_{n+1})$ in terms of $(b_n,c_n).$